# How to move an image upwards in html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to HTML and I wanted to have an image in my page, but when I use `<hr>` to separate it from other stuff they cross each other. So I want to move my image up a little. Here's the code I've been using:

```
<html dir="rtl"> <body> ... <img src="20161125_041749.jpg" alt="my pic" style= "width: 108px; height: 130px; float:left;" ... </div> </body> </html>
```

I'm not using `<head>` nor `<style>` tags.
I've been trying to use position:relative;top:-10px; ,but I can't figure out how to use it or it has some problem with the "float".
Coud anyone please help me what to do?

Thanks in advance and Thanks to all who have tried to solve it so far...

Comment: It may be hard to give you answer with only a single line of your code. Perhaps creating a better example of your problem using https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: atleast give full code of yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the value of **top** as you needed

```css
#img{
  position: relative;
  top:-10px;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1bSf.jpg" alt="my pic" style= "width: 108px; height: 130px; float:left;" id="img">
```

Answer (score 1):

This root issue (that the image and `<hr>` cross each other) sounds like a clearfix problem.

When you have a floating element, it may appear to "overlap" non-floating elements:

```css
#float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: right;
}

hr {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="float"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id auctor tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst</p>
<hr>
```

But instead of trying to just move the float up, you might want to add `clear: both` to your `<hr>`:

```css
#float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: right;
}

hr {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="float"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id auctor tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst</p>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="20161125_041749.jpg" alt="my pic" style= "width: 108px; height: 130px; float:left;margin-bottom:5px">
```

margin-bottom:5px;
will work fine 
or you can change values according to your need

or provide demo code for better view